# PHP: How to test if database link is still valid?

Tags: php, database-connection

When one retrieves a database $link with [mysql_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php), how can one check if that link is still valid after some time? (I am not asking whether the returned is valid, I mean later)

Comment: Why would it not be valid? Are you concerned about the connection being closed programmatically? Timing out? Something else?

Comment: +1 to counter the downvote. This is a decent question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`mysql_ping()`](http://php.net/mysql_ping) or [`mysqli_ping()`](http://php.net/mysqli_ping) for this. However, in a regular web application you should just execute your queries and abort with an error if a query failed (or retry once).

Comment: Ok, it is the query execution that will fail. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to test.

Just execute the query, and you will see...